# Как разместить элемент legend снизу в центре?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, можно ли разместить элемент legend снизу и центрировать его, если нет то каким способом можно выполнить данную задачу?

```css
h1,p {
  text-align:center;
};

.legend {
  padding: 0 10px;
};
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <h1>The Best Services</h1>
  <p>We provide the best services in the world We provide the best services in the world We <br>provide the best services in the world</p>
  <legend>
    <button>Click</button>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: В css что у вас творится? Лишние `;`, а класса `legend` у вас в принципе в коде нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто, только обертка нужна для текста внутри `fieldset`.

```css
h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset,
legend,
.wrapper {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

legend {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>The Best Services</h1>
    <p>We provide the best services in the world We provide the best services in the world We <br>provide the best services in the world</p>
  </div>
  <legend align="center">
    <button>Click</button>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помог!